# radius of convergence of the series $\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty q^{n^2}z^n$ where $|q|<1$

Tags: complex-analysis, power-series

I am trying to find the radius of convergence of the series $$\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty q^{n^2}z^n$$ where $|q|<1$.

My intuition is that the radius of convergence is $\infty$, as

$$\frac{1}{\lim \sup\limits_{n\rightarrow \infty}|a_n|^{\frac{1}{n}}}$$

$$=\frac{1}{\lim \sup\limits_{n\rightarrow \infty}|q^{n^2}|^{\frac{1}{n}}}$$
$$=\frac{1}{\lim \sup\limits_{n\rightarrow \infty}|q|^{n}}$$
$$=\frac{1}{0}$$
$$=\infty$$
So the series converges everywhere.

Comment: The handling of "infinity" is very casual, but it is true by the root test that the series converges everywhere.